# Seeking clarity on data sanitization fields for settings textarea

Tags: settings-api, sanitization

Wanting to learn more about the settings page I wanted to be able to add code such as Google Adsense, Google Analytics and anything code related in a textarea within a custom settings page but I've been unable to track down a previous Q&A.

Upon research I've run across "[Default Wordpress settings API data sanitization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61024/default-wordpress-settings-api-data-sanitization)" which indicated WordPress doesn't do any data sanitation outside of the default.  When I research further I've come across [The WordPress Settings API, Part 7: Validation, Sanitisation, and Input](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-wordpress-settings-api-part-7-validation-sanitisation-and-input--wp-25289) which shows to use [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) and then referenced [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) but that is only on the index.php on output if I'm understanding correctly.  Further searching I found "[Proper Way To Sanitize And Validate Options When Using The Settings Api?](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/proper-way-to-sanitize-and-validate-options-when-using-the-settings-api)" which only recommended a few other links that didn't answer my question.

When I'm using a textarea in my settings page:

```
function curious_darth() { 
    $question_dark_side = get_option('darth_vader');
    ?>
    <textarea rows="12" cols="60" type='text' name='darth_vader[light_saber]' value='<?php if (isset($question_dark_side['light_saber']) ) echo sanitize_text_field($question_dark_side['light_saber']); ?>'><?php echo isset($question_dark_side['light_saber'] ) ? $question_dark_side['light_saber'] : false; ?></textarea>
    <?php
}
```

Is there a way to sanitize the data on input so that on output it will not render and if I want it to render somewhere in particular what is the proper way to render text that has had it's HTML escaped?